# How to get total time of event in firebase analytics with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I am using firebase analytics with flutter. I have used set screen for event log but i want to know total time in hours is there any way to show that instead of %.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPihA.png)